# Where does top command get all the data for CPU Utilization?

Tags: linux, top

When I run the `top` command, the third line is;

`Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.2%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.1%st`

From where does top command get this data? Does it get from `/proc`?, if yes, what is the exact location?

Comment: Yes, it usess procfs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are questioning for the exact location of the CPU usage. This is `/proc/stat`:

```
$ head -n 3 /proc/stat
cpu  1751981 185577 398478 28868975 69445 32 27028 0 0 0
cpu0 954878 88888 186567 14433502 19750 0 600 0 0 0
cpu1 797103 96688 211911 14435473 49694 31 26428 0 0 0
```

The format is explained in the Kernel Documentation (`filesystems/proc.txt`); I bolded the `top`abbreviations:

> The very first  "cpu" line aggregates the  numbers in all  of the
>   other "cpuN" lines.  These numbers identify the amount of time the CPU
>   has spent performing different kinds of work.  Time units are in
>   USER_HZ (typically hundredths of a second).  The meanings of the
>   columns are as follows, from left to right:
>
> - **us**er: normal processes executing in user mode
> - **ni**ce: niced processes executing in user mode
> - **sy**stem: processes executing in kernel mode
> - **id**le: twiddling thumbs
> - io**wa**it: waiting for I/O to complete
> - irq: servicing interrupts [hard interrupts **hi**]
> - softirq: servicing softirqs [soft interrupts **si**]
> - **st**eal: involuntary wait
> - guest: running a normal guest
> - guest_nice: running a niced guest

General informations about your CPU you can get from `/proc/cpuinfo`, but this is not related to the CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Procfs could be found in `/proc`.
Please read on this: [Exploring procfs](http://linuxgazette.net/115/nirendra.html)

> Procfs is a virtual file system in linux mounted in /proc, and serves multiple purposes including access to kernel information in userland or for debugging. One of the features which makes Linux special to me is access to process information as a text stream. A lot of linux commands (ps, top, pstree, etc.) rely on this filesystem for information.

You might look through `top` source code which could be found in `coreutils` GNU package.