# How to read 'top' results

Tags: memory, cpu, cpu-usage, top

I am running a software and while it is running, I want to know how much CPU usage or RAM it occupies... along with maybe other things that could be interesting. For that purpose, I need to know exactly what do words like `VIRT`, `SHR`, `N` etc mean. I have tried to find it on Google but could not. Can someone please guide me to a source where I can read about these in detail for the `top` command?

Also, as per my understanding, `%CPU` shows CPU usage and `%MEM`shows the percentage of RAM that is being used. Is that correct?

Also, I don't know how is it possible that at one time 3-4 users are using 100% of CPU and sometimes someone is even using 400%. What does that mean?

Comment: Have you tried `man top`?

Comment: Regarding the %CPU, it means that you have (at least) a quad-core CPU or (at least) four processors (or two dual core processors).

Comment: Yes I have tried `man top`. It only tells me what `options` I can use. Not how to read the results.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example output of `top`:

```
top - 14:21:40 up 7 days, 21:57,  7 users,  load average: 0.13, 0.04, 0.04
Tasks: 107 total,   2 running, 105 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :  1.0% us,  1.0% sy,  0.0% ni, 96.1% id,  1.9% wa,  0.0% hi,  0.0% si
Cpu1  :  1.0% us,  1.0% sy,  0.0% ni, 98.0% id,  0.0% wa,  0.0% hi,  0.0% si
Mem:   2050756k total,  2034236k used,    16520k free,    22252k buffers
Swap:  2097144k total,    87108k used,  2010036k free,  1609212k cached
```

- The first line is easily interpreted, only why there are three different load averages is not obvious: These values use three different time scales.
- Second line: summary of tasks, grouped by their state
- The CPU line has two modes, either

  `Cpu(s):  1.0% us,  0.5% sy,  0.0% ni, 98.5% id,  0.0% wa,  0.0% hi,  0.0% si`

  where all CPU cores are summarized or like in the example above, where every core has its own line. You can toggle between these modes with <kbd>1</kbd>. Every core can be used to 100%, so with two cores the *total* maximum value ist 200%.

  The two letter abbreviations are bolded in the following list (c&p from an [older answer](https://superuser.com/a/587105/195224)):

  > - **us**er: normal processes executing in user mode
  > - **ni**ce: niced processes executing in user mode
  > - **sy**stem: processes executing in kernel mode
  > - **id**le: twiddling thumbs
  > - io**wa**it: waiting for I/O to complete
  > - irq: servicing interrupts [hard interrupts **hi**]
  > - softirq: servicing softirqs [soft interrupts **si**]
  > - **st**eal: involuntary wait
- Mem and Swap is for physical RAM and swap space, respectively.
- The process list is explained in detail in top`s man page (*2a. DESCRIPTIONS of Fields*). As your man page seems incomplete, below is an excerpt; there are also copies of the complete [man page on the internet](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top). By default these columns are shown (customize with <kbd>f</kbd>):

  `PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND`

  To address your specific question about the CPU usage: If a process run ins parallel, i.e. can use multiple CPU cores, a usage of 400% indicates, that 4 cores are used completely.

---

> **PID**  --  Process Id:
>             The task's unique process ID, which periodically wraps, though never restarting at zero.
>
> **PPID**  --  Parent Process Pid:
>             The process ID of a task's parent.
>
> **RUSER**  --  Real User Name:
>             The real user name of the task's owner.
>
> **UID**  --  User Id:
>             The effective user ID of the task's owner.
>   Blockquote
>
> **USER**  --  User Name:
>             The effective user name of the task's owner.
>
> **GROUP**  --  Group Name:
>             The effective group name of the task's owner.
>
> **TTY**  --  Controlling Tty:
>             The  name  of  the  controlling terminal.  This is usually the device (serial port, pty, etc.) from which the process was
>   started, and
>             which it uses for input or output.  However, a task need not be associated with a terminal, in which case you'll see '?' displayed.
>
> **PR**  --  Priority:
>             The priority of the task.
>
> **NI**  --  Nice value:
>             The nice value of the task.  A negative nice value means higher priority, whereas a positive nice value means lower priority. 
>   Zero in
>             this field simply means priority will not be adjusted in determining a task's dispatchability.
>
> **P**  --  Last used CPU (SMP):
>             A  number  representing the last used processor.  In a true SMP environment this will likely change frequently since the kernel
>   inten-
>             tionally uses weak affinity.  Also, the very act of running top may break this weak affinity and cause more processes to  change 
>   CPUs
>             more often (because of the extra demand for cpu time).
>
> **%CPU**  --  CPU usage:
>             The  task's  share  of  the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.  In a true
>   SMP
>             environment, if 'Irix mode' is Off, top will operate in 'Solaris mode' where a task's cpu usage will be divided by the total
>   number of
>             CPUs.  You toggle 'Irix/Solaris' modes with the 'I' interactive command.
>
> **TIME**  --  CPU Time:
>             Total CPU time the task has used since it started.  When 'Cumulative mode' is On, each process is listed with the cpu time that
>   it and
>             its dead children has used.  You toggle 'Cumulative mode' with 'S', which is a command-line option and an  interactive  command.
>   See
>             the 'S' interactive command for additional information regarding this mode.
>
> **TIME+**  --  CPU Time, hundredths:
>             The same as 'TIME', but reflecting more granularity through hundredths of a second.
>
> **%MEM**  --  Memory usage (RES): A task's currently used share of available physical memory.
>
> **VIRT**  --  Virtual Image (kb):
>             The  total  amount  of  virtual  memory  used  by the task.  It includes all code, data and shared libraries plus pages that have
>   been
>             swapped out. `VIRT = SWAP + RES`
>
> **SWAP**  --  Swapped size (kb):
>             The swapped out portion of a task's total virtual memory image.
>
> **RES**  --  Resident size (kb):
>             The non-swapped physical memory a task has used. 
>             `RES = CODE + DATA`
>
> **CODE**  --  Code size (kb):
>             The amount of physical memory devoted to executable code, also known as the 'text resident set' size or TRS.
>
> **DATA**  --  Data+Stack size (kb):
>             The amount of physical memory devoted to other than executable code, also known as the 'data resident set' size or DRS.
>
> **SHR**  --  Shared Mem size (kb):
>             The amount of shared memory used by a task.  It simply reflects memory that could be potentially shared with other processes.
>
> **nFLT**  --  Page Fault count:
>             The number of major page faults that have occurred for a task.  A page fault occurs when a process attempts to read from or
>   write to a
>             virtual  page  that  is not currently present in its address space.  A major page fault is when disk access is involved in making
>   that
>             page available.
>
> **nDRT**  --  Dirty Pages count:
>             The number of pages that have been modified since they were last written to disk.  Dirty pages must be written to disk before the
>   cor-
>             responding physical memory location can be used for some other virtual page.
>
> **S**  --  Process Status
>             The status of the task which can be one of:
>    **D** = uninterruptible sleep,
>     **R** = running,
>    **S** = sleeping,
>    **T** = traced or stopped,
>   **Z** = zombie.
>   Tasks  shown as running should be more properly thought of as 'ready to run'  --  their task_struct is simply represented on the
>   Linux
>             run-queue.  Even without a true SMP machine, you may see numerous tasks in this state depending  on  top's  delay  interval 
>   and  nice
>             value.
>
> **Command**  --  Command line or Program name:
>             Display  the  command  line used to start a task or the name of the associated program.  You toggle between command line and name
>   with
>             'c', which is both a command-line option and an interactive command.
>     When you've chosen to display command lines, processes without a command line (like kernel threads) will be shown with only 
>   the  pro-
>             gram name in parentheses, as in this example:
>                   ( mdrecoveryd )
>    Either  form  of display is subject to potential truncation if it's too long to fit in this field's current width.  That width
>   depends
>             upon other fields selected, their order and the current screen width.
>      *Note:* The 'Command' field/column is unique, in that it is not fixed-width.  When displayed, this column will be allocated all 
>   remain-
>             ing screen width (up to the maximum 512 characters) to provide for the potential growth of program names into command lines.
>
> **WCHAN**  --  Sleeping in Function:
>             Depending  on the availability of the kernel link map ('System.map'), this field will show the name or the address of the
>   kernel func-
>             tion in which the task is currently sleeping.  Running tasks will display a dash ('-') in this column.
>    *Note:* By displaying this field, top's own working set will be increased by over 700Kb.  Your only means of reducing that overhead
>   will
>             be to stop and restart top.
>
> **Flags**  --  Task Flags:
>             This  column  represents  the  task's  current scheduling flags which are expressed in hexadecimal notation and with zeros
>   suppressed.
>             These flags are officially documented in .  Less formal documentation can also be found  on  the  'Fields  select'
>   and
>             'Order fields' screens.